# Is there a way I can combine two separate iterator blocks to one?

Tags: c#, iterator, refactoring, ienumerable, yield-return

I almost know its impossible and meaningless, but just trying to learn.. I have:

```
public IEnumerable<IEnumerable<object>> GetMany()
{
    while (someCondition)
        yield return GetFew();
}

static IEnumerable<object> GetFew()
{
    while (someOtherCondition)
        yield return new object();
}
```

Can I combine the two and form one method? Can two different iterator blocks lie in one method?

**Edit:** I am not asking how to solve the problem I have at hand. I'm trying to learn something new, so the larger question is "there a way two separate blocks can be made to work in one function"? I ask because there are anonymous types and closure in C# where you can have something new defined inside a method itself without a named type or method. Likewise for blocks?

Comment: Can you provide more details? What yo want to do? Look at SelectMany Union.

Comment: I do have nothing to do. And certainly I can live with two blocks. Just trying to learn when I accidentally happened to code in one method and had to refactor to two methods to get compiled. Thats when I thought about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're asking for is anonymous iterator blocks.  Eric Lippert [blogged on the subject](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/08/24/iterator-blocks-part-seven-why-no-anonymous-iterators.aspx) a while back.  In short, he said that it would be a wonderful feature that he'd love to see, but it's extraordinarily difficult to actually implement such a feature, so it has not been added to the language so far (and adding it in the future is unlikely).

Comment: The difficulty is not just that it is a very tricky feature, but also that implementing it on top of the existing architecture would have been a lot of work. VB, which did not have iterators previously, just added iterator blocks and they added anonymous iterators while they were at it. I hope that with the improved Roslyn architecture the feature will be cheaper in a hypothetical future version of C#.

Comment: (And you'll note that in C# 5 we did add both async nominal methods and async lambdas.)

Answer (score 3):

In short, no, you cannot have nested `yield` iterator within the same method.

`yield` is compiled at the method level. Every time you do `yield return` it will exit the method, and later continue where it left off. This means that if you nest `yield` statements, they will still be operating at a method level, not a block level.